# Как получить ключ в массиве, не зная значений?

Tags: php

Такая проблема:

```
<?php
    $ses = $_POST['PHPSESSID'];
    $params = array(
        'PHPSESSID' => $ses,
    );

    $url = "https://сайт.com/скрипт.php";

    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID='.$ses);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    file_put_contents('test.php', iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $result));

    echo "<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' content ='0; 
URL=https://сайт.com/test.php?PHPSESSID=".$ses."'></head></html>";
?>
```

Есть массив $_POST. Но я не знаю её содержимое. Хочу составить новый массив, состоящий из некоторых элементов массива $_POST. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Задача не понятна. Что значит `из некоторых элементов массива $_POST`? Значит какие-то конкретные элементы в `$_POST` все-таки ожидаются?

Comment: да, мне с другой странице передаются на этот скрипт переменные через POST запрос, но я не знаю имена этих переменных, т.к. они приходят от сервера, к которому я не имею доступ. Соответственно, я не смогу обратиться к значению переменной не знаяю ключа

Comment: Если правильно понял, что нужно, то `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {...}`

Comment: то есть у меня в переменной $key будет текущий ключ?

Comment: да. А в $value значение, соответственно

Comment: всё, понял, что-то не сообразил. Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если правильно понял, что нужно, то foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {...} – Nikita Umnov

Спасибо, это то, что мне нужно было!